# How to apply imported stylesheet to template tag content for a custom element?

Tags: javascript, html, dropzone.js, custom-element, html5-template

Here is the code I am trying to use

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="dropzone.js"></script>
<link href="dropzone.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<template id="dropzoneTemplate">
 <div id="dZUpload" class="dropzone">
    <div class="dz-default dz-message"></div>
 </div>
</template>
<dropzone></dropzone>

<script>
    var DropzoneElementPrototype = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

    DropzoneElementPrototype.createdCallback = function () {
        var t = document.querySelector('#uploadImageTemplate');
        var clone = document.importNode(t.content, true);
        this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(clone);
    };

    var DropzoneElement = document.registerElement('dropzone', {
        prototype: DropzoneElementPrototype
    });

</script>
```

But the `imported stylesheet` **dropzone.css** is not getting applied to the content inside `template` tag, i.e. **class dropzone** is not getting its styles from **dropzone.css** so the styles in the imported file is not getting applied to elements like `div` inside `template` tag.

I have also tried to put this link tag inside the template tag, but that doesn't work either.

Is it possible to apply imported stylesheet to template tag content for a custom element?

Comment: Both <link> and @import are now supported inside <template> elements to apply scoped styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `@import css` style rule inside your `<template>` element:

```
<template id="dropzoneTemplate">
    <style>
       @import url( 'dropzone.css' )
    </style>
    <div id="dZUpload" class="dropzone">
          <div class="dz-default dz-message"></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Note:

- According to the [CSS2 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#at-import), `@import` rule must precede any other rules except `@charset`.
- If your stylesheet defines a `@font-face`, it must be included in the main document too.